# Tokenizing a raw string in c

Tags: c, parsing, token, space

I would like to tokenize a string, but in a very special way.

I have the following string, formed by 3 groups of words, separated by a space:

> string = abc def ghi

The thing is that I would like to load into another string all the content of **string** variable until the second space. That is, I would like to get:

> result = abc def

And not only abc (that solution was in other forums). Please, note that the length of each word could differ.

How would I do that?

Comment: a rare string?  I would Ebay it.  Make some $ that way.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [cstring api](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstring)?

Comment: @thang Or sell it on kol at least.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to load in one string all the content of string variable
>   until the second space

How about:

```
char *space = strchr(string, ' ');
if (!space)
    error;
space++;
space = strchr(space, ' ');
if (!space)
    error;
```

Or if you know there will always be exactly 3 words, do a single `strrchr` (reverse). Or maybe do 2 `sscanfs` and then join the strings, or 2 `strtok`s etc.